# What is the area of △ QPO?

Tags: geometry, area

Parallelogram $ABCD$ has area of 1.

Centers of the $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ sides are labeled M, N.

The $\overline{CM}$ and $\overline{DN}$ lines intersect at $O$ while their intersections with the $\overline{AB}$ line are marked
$Q$, $P$.

What is the area of $\triangle$ $QPO$?

[image]

EDIT:

Here's my solution with the help of @Dubs and @Vasya:

[image]

Comment: The height of the triangle is $\frac{3}{4}$ of the height of the $ABCD$ and the base is $3$ times the base of $ABCD$.

Comment: @Dubs ok base is 3 times, assuming base of left and right triangle is same as side AB, but how you've deduced height or triangle as 3/4?

Comment: $O$ is at the midpoint of $MNCD$ and $M,N$ are the midpoints of $ABCD$. Basically, you are cutting the height into 2 twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using proportional segments theorem: $BP:AP=BN:AD=1:2$. Thus, $BP=AB$ similarly, $QA=AB$. So $QP=3AB$ and the height is $\frac{3}{4}$ of the height to $AB$. Thus, $A_{\triangle{QPO}}=3 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{8}$

Comment: Thanks, but A is point, it doesn't have area. But I assume you meant area of QPO is 9/8. Am I right?

Comment: Btw. it's right. I will also propose my solution but will mark yours as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterParada: Yes, that's what I meant, I was just in a hurry :) Glad you understand the solution.